# NetworkX Directed Graph Generation

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

Is there a function available in Python's NetworkX for generating random directed graphs with a maximum Euclidean distance between any two connected nodes? For example, for nodes separated by a certain Euclidean distance, there is a probability p of those nodes being connected and for all other nodes separated by greater than this distance, they will not be connected in the graph that is generated.

Comment: Are you saying if their distance is less than a value the probability is p and if it is greater than that value it is 0?  [it's unclear from your question how you handle short distances]

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusing wording.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a threshold such that distances greater than the threshold do not exist, and all edges shorter than that threshold have probability `p`, then you're in luck.  [if it's not the same probability for all shorter edges, it's still doable but a bit harder]

Start by building a random geometric graph `G`.  This is a graph whose nodes are put in place uniformly at random and any two are connected if they are within a threshold distance from each other.

Then create a new directed graph which has each direction of the edges in `G` with probability `p`.

```
import networkx as nx
import random
N=100 # 100 nodes
D = 0.2 #threshold distance of 0.2
G = nx.random_geometric_graph(N, D)
H = nx.Digraph()
H.add_nodes_from(G.edges())
p = 0.1  #keep 10% of the edges
for u,v in G.edges():
    if random.random()<p:
        H.add_edge(u,v)
    if random.random()<p:
        H.add_edge(v,u)
```

Comment: I eventually got around to implementing this, but your suggestion wasn't really giving me what I was after. I ended up using "random_geometric_graph" but instead of creating an empty DiGraph, I created a new graph using the "to_directed" function and removed random edges afterwards (instead of adding random edges). The issue I had with your method was that the position attributes were not being copied over to the new graph, but "to_directed" does a deep copy so that information was retained.